# Stop and Start a service via batch or cmd file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

How can I script a bat or cmd to stop and start a service reliably with error checking (or let me know that it wasn't successful for whatever reason)?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Use the `SC` (service control) command, it gives you a lot more options than just `start` & `stop`.

```
  DESCRIPTION:
          SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
          NT Service Controller and services.
  USAGE:
      sc <server> [command] [service name]  ...

      The option <server> has the form "\\ServerName"
      Further help on commands can be obtained by typing: "sc [command]"
      Commands:
        query-----------Queries the status for a service, or
                        enumerates the status for types of services.
        queryex---------Queries the extended status for a service, or
                        enumerates the status for types of services.
        start-----------Starts a service.
        pause-----------Sends a PAUSE control request to a service.
        interrogate-----Sends an INTERROGATE control request to a service.
        continue--------Sends a CONTINUE control request to a service.
        stop------------Sends a STOP request to a service.
        config----------Changes the configuration of a service (persistant).
        description-----Changes the description of a service.
        failure---------Changes the actions taken by a service upon failure.
        qc--------------Queries the configuration information for a service.
        qdescription----Queries the description for a service.
        qfailure--------Queries the actions taken by a service upon failure.
        delete----------Deletes a service (from the registry).
        create----------Creates a service. (adds it to the registry).
        control---------Sends a control to a service.
        sdshow----------Displays a service's security descriptor.
        sdset-----------Sets a service's security descriptor.
        GetDisplayName--Gets the DisplayName for a service.
        GetKeyName------Gets the ServiceKeyName for a service.
        EnumDepend------Enumerates Service Dependencies.

      The following commands don't require a service name:
      sc <server> <command> <option>
        boot------------(ok | bad) Indicates whether the last boot should
                        be saved as the last-known-good boot configuration
        Lock------------Locks the Service Database
        QueryLock-------Queries the LockStatus for the SCManager Database
  EXAMPLE:
          sc start MyService
```

Comment: I agree that this is better than net start/stop.  Note that there is an option to touch services on remote machines as well.

Comment: Great answer. But you need to be administrator to run 'SC start service'. I found a solution for that [here](http://superuser.com/questions/419194/is-there-a-way-to-allow-standard-users-to-restart-stop-start-the-print-spooler).(The accepted answer contains the solution)

Comment: The problem with SC is that the command returns immediately and not after the action is complete. If you want to restart a service via batch file (stop then start), the stop returns immediately, the start then fails because the service isn't stopped. Net stop/start returns after the action is complete, so doesn't have this problem.

Comment: is there a way to check if service is stopped properly?? in 2020?

Answer (score 234):

```
net start [serviceName]
```

and

```
net stop [serviceName]
```

tell you whether they have succeeded or failed pretty clearly. For example

```
U:\>net stop alerter
The Alerter service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.
```

If running from a batch file, you have access to the ERRORLEVEL of the return code. 0 indicates success. Anything higher indicates failure.

As a bat file, `error.bat`:

```
@echo off
net stop alerter
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
exit
:error
echo There was a problem
pause
```

The output looks like this:

```
U:\>error.bat
The Alerter service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.

There was a problem
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Return Codes**

```
 - 0 = Success
 - 1 = Not Supported
 - 2 = Access Denied
 - 3 = Dependent Services Running
 - 4 = Invalid Service Control
 - 5 = Service Cannot Accept Control
 - 6 = Service Not Active
 - 7 = Service Request Timeout
 - 8 = Unknown Failure
 - 9 = Path Not Found
 - 10 = Service Already Running
 - 11 = Service Database Locked
 - 12 = Service Dependency Deleted
 - 13 = Service Dependency Failure
 - 14 = Service Disabled
 - 15 = Service Logon Failure
 - 16 = Service Marked For Deletion
 - 17 = Service No Thread
 - 18 = Status Circular Dependency
 - 19 = Status Duplicate Name
 - 20 = Status Invalid Name
 - 21 = Status Invalid Parameter 
 - 22 = Status Invalid Service Account
 - 23 = Status Service Exists
 - 24 = Service Already Paused
```

**Edit 20.04.2015**

Return Codes:

> The NET command does not return the documented Win32_Service class return codes (Service Not Active,Service Request Timeout, etc) and for many errors will simply return Errorlevel 2.

Look here: http://ss64.com/nt/net_service.html

Comment: `NET` *is not* just for service related functions whilst `SC` *is* just for service related functions.

Comment: This answer is better because "net" command blocks and wait for the service to start or stop before the batch script continues executing.

Comment: Since (as the Edit says) most of the time the `errorlevel` returned is 2, [see here how to interpret the error result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187380/start-a-windows-service-from-a-batch-script-and-take-appropriate-action-based-on).

Answer (score 29):

You can use the NET START command and then check the ERRORLEVEL environment variable, e.g.

```
net start [your service]
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo Could not start service.
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Service started successfully.
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
```

Disclaimer: I've written this from the top of my head, but I think it'll work.

Answer (score 11):

I have created my personal batch file for this, mine is a little different but feel free to modify as you see fit.
I created this a little while ago because I was bored and wanted to make a simple way for people to be able to input ending, starting, stopping, or setting to auto. This BAT file simply requests that you input the service name and it will do the rest for you. I didn't realize that he was looking for something that stated any error, I must have misread that part. Though typically this can be done by inputting >> output.txt on the end of the line.

The %var% is just a way for the user to be able to input their own service into this, instead of having to go modify the bat file every time that you want to start/stop a different service.

If I am wrong, anyone can feel free to correct me on this.

```
@echo off
set /p c= Would you like to start a service [Y/N]?
  if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :1
  if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :2
    :1  
    set /p var= Service name: 
:2 
set /p c= Would you like to stop a service [Y/N]?
  if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :3
  if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :4
    :3  
    set /p var1= Service name:
:4
set /p c= Would you like to disable a service [Y/N]?
  if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :5
  if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :6
    :5  
    set /p var2= Service name:
:6 
set /p c= Would you like to set a service to auto [Y/N]?
  if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :7
  if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :10
    :7  
    set /p var3= Service name:
:10
sc start %var%
sc stop %var1%
sc config %var2% start=disabled
sc config %var3% start=auto
```

Comment: Typically, code only answers are not appreciated. Could you elaborate on your solution or add some explanatory comments?

Comment: I created this a little while ago because I was bored and wanted to make a simple way for people to be able to input ending, starting, stopping, or setting to auto. This BAT file simply requests that you input the service name and it will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of checking codes, this works too

```
net start "Apache tomcat" || goto ExitError

:End  
exit 0  

:ExitError  
echo An error has occurred while starting the tomcat services  
exit 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Using the return codes from `net start` and `net stop` seems like the best method to me. Try a look at this: [Net Start return codes](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31708197/net-start-return-codes.aspx).

Comment: The linked page no longer exists. As such, this is more of a comment now.

Answer (score 7):

Syntax always gets me.... so...

Here is explicitly how to add a line to a batch file that will kill a remote service (on another machine) if you are an admin on both machines, run the .bat as an administrator, and the machines are on the same domain. The machine name follows the UNC format \myserver

```
sc \\ip.ip.ip.ip stop p4_1
```

In this case... p4_1 was both the Service Name and the Display Name, when you view the Properties for the service in Service Manager. You must use the Service Name.

For your Service Ops junkies... be sure to append your reason code and comment! i.e. '4' which equals 'Planned' and comment 'Stopping server for maintenance'

```
sc \\ip.ip.ip.ip stop p4_1 4 Stopping server for maintenance
```

Comment: How do I do this if I need to use another user ID and password to log on ?

Comment: You run `CMD` as the other user/ID by doing `runas /user:Domain\UserName cmd` then enter your password.  CMD will start running as the specified user account.

Answer (score 5):

We'd like to think that "net stop " will stop the service.  Sadly, reality isn't that black and white.  If the service takes a long time to stop, the command will return before the service has stopped.  You won't know, though, unless you check errorlevel.

The solution seems to be to loop round looking for the state of the service until it is stopped, with a pause each time round the loop.

But then again...

I'm seeing the first service take a long time to stop, then the "net stop" for a subsequent service just appears to do nothing.  Look at the service in the services manager, and its state is still "Started" - no change to "Stopping".  Yet I can stop this second service manually using the SCM, and it stops in 3 or 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

or you can start remote service with this cmd : `sc \\<computer> start <service>`

Answer (score 4):

I just used Jonas' example above and created full list of 0 to 24 errorlevels.  Other post is correct that `net start` and `net stop` only use `errorlevel` 0 for success and 2 for failure.

But this is what worked for me:

```
net stop postgresql-9.1
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo Access Denied - Could not stop service
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Service stopped successfully
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
```

Change `stop` to `start` and works in reverse.

Answer (score 4):

Manual service restart is ok - services.msc has "Restart" button, but in command line both sc and net commands lacks a "restart" switch and if restart is scheduled in cmd/bat file, service is stopped and started immediately, sometimes it gets an error because service is not stopped yet, it needs some time to shut things down.

This may generate an error:
sc stop 
sc start

It is a good idea to insert timeout, I use ping (it pings every 1 second):
sc stop 
ping localhost -n 60
sc start

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Windows 10 command to start System Restore using batch :

```
sc config swprv start= Auto
```

You may also like those commands :

- Change registry value to auto start System restore

  REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore" /v DisableSR /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
- Create a system restore point

  Wmic.exe /Namespace:\root\default Path SystemRestore Call CreateRestorePoint "djibe saved your PC", 100, 12
- Change System Restore disk usage

  vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=10%

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

1. [**SC**](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)
2. [**NET STOP/START**](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html)
3. [**PsService**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psservice)
4. [**WMIC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic)
5. Powershell is also [easy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-service?view=powershell-7) for [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-7) option

SC and NET are already given as an anwests. PsService add some neat features but requires a download from Microsoft.

But my favorite way is with WMIC as the WQL syntax gives a powerful way to manage more than one service with one line (WMI objects can be also used through powershell/vbscript/jscript/c#).

The easiest way to use it:

```
wmic service MyService call StartService
wmic service MyService  call StopService
```

And example with WQL

```
wmic service where "name like '%%32Time%%' and ErrorControl='Normal'" call StartService
```

This will start all services that have a name containing `32Time` and have normal error control.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service) are the methods you can use.

With :

```
wmic service get /FORMAT:VALUE
```

you can see the available information about the services.

Answer (score 2):

`SC` can do everything with services... start, stop, check, configure, and more...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can find the stop does not work..

My SQlServer sometimes does this. Using the following commandline kills it. If you really really need your script to kill stuff that doesn't stop. I would have it do this as a last resort

```
taskkill /pid [pid number] /f
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a windows service in C#, the stop/uninstall/build/install/start loop got too tiring. Wrote a mini script, called it `reploy.bat` and dropped in my Visual Studio output directory (one that has the built service executable) to automate the  loop.

Just set these 3 vars

`servicename` : this shows up on the Windows Service control panel (services.msc)

`slndir` : folder (not the full path) containing your solution (.sln) file

`binpath` : full path (not the folder path) to the service executable from the build

NOTE: This needs to be run from the Visual Studio Developer Command Line for the `msbuild` command to work.

```
SET servicename="My Amazing Service"
SET slndir="C:dir\that\contains\sln\file"
SET binpath="C:path\to\service.exe"
SET currdir=%cd%

call net stop %servicename%
call sc delete %servicename%
cd %slndir%
call msbuild 
cd %bindir%
call sc create %servicename% binpath=%binpath%
call net start %servicename%
cd %currdir%
```

Maybe this helps someone :)

Comment: why sc delete always?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any of the answers above to offer a satisfactory solution so I wrote the following batch script...

```
:loop
net stop tomcat8 
sc query tomcat8 | find "STOPPED"
if errorlevel 1 (
  timeout 1
  goto loop
)
:loop2
net start tomcat8
sc query tomcat8 | find "RUNNING"
if errorlevel 1 (
  timeout 1
  goto loop2
)
```

It keeps running **net stop** until the service status is STOPPED, only after the status is stopped does it run **net start**.  If a service takes a long time to stop, **net stop** can terminate unsuccessfully. If for some reason the service does not start successfully, it will keep attempting to start the service until the state is RUNNING.

Answer (score 0):

With this can start a service or program that need a service

```
@echo
taskkill /im service.exe /f
taskkill /im service.exe /f
set "reply=y"
set /p "reply=Restart service? [y|n]: "
if /i not "%reply%" == "y" goto :eof
cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
start service.lnk
sc start service
eof
exit
```