# Stop/Start Service - Handling STOP_PENDING and START_PENDING

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do you make your stop/start service scripts gracefully handling the services that get stuck in STOP_PENDING or START_PENDING...

Related with SC STOP and START. [Stop and Start a service via batch or cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file)

I have one aproach in mind, but I don't like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way i'm approaching the stop.

- Stop: sc %host% stop %service% || ECHO ERROR! && EXIT -1
- Loop waiting for state to be STOPPED. 
  Loop with a maximum number of iterations (e.g. 30). Testing if service is stopped (e.g. sc %host% query %service% | find /i "STOPPED"). Wait some seconds in each iteration (e.g. 10). Reaching the maximum iterations, try to kill the process using taskkill (e.g. work the output of sc queryex Alerter | find /i "PID").

Answer (score 5):

First open **service.msc**, in the properties dialog for your targeted service go to the **Recovery Tab** *(run -> services.msc -> right-click *Target-Service* -> Properties -> Recovery tab*)

Make sure the ***First\Second\Subsequent*** failures are all set to : **Take No Action**.
[image]

Get the PID of your target service using: **sc queryex ServiceName**:

Kill the process using **taskkill /f /pid your_PID_number**

Comment: Best answer so far. This one will always work, no matter what.

Comment: how do you kill tasks that are in STOP_PENDING state and have PID Number 0?

Comment: @Akito except when no PID is returned like in my case

Answer (score 3):

For me sometimes a 'Windows service' is hanging when I have the window `services.msc` open. I can't kill the process, neither use `net stop` or `sc stop`.

But when I close the `services.msc` window, the service immediately stops.