# Cannot start a VB Windows Service from batch

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, batch-file, windows-server-2003

I created a custom windows service in Visual Basic using Visual Studios '05.

The service is on our server which is running Windows Server 2003. I have installed the service, and it runs perfectly when I go into `Computer Management` and `Start` the service manually.

I have created a batch file to start the service using the `NET START` command. Whenever I run the batch file, the service doesn't start. I get this message from the command prompt:

> The 'Service Name' is starting.
>
> The 'Service Name' could not be started. The service did not report an error. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3543.

I'm not sure what to do. (Been "googling" for a couple of hours.) It starts up when I manually run it, but it wont start via the batch file. Thanks!

Comment: execute the batch file "Run as administrator"

Comment: It's on windows server 2003. There isn't an option to "Run as administrator." Also, I'm logged in as the Admin. Thanks!

Comment: refer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325859 to enable Run As option in Windows 2003

Comment: Well, I have plans to run the batch file as "scheduled task." It needs to be run every night on its own.

Comment: refer http://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservergen/thread/d7e17e3e-a041-4faf-8550-fb3036e99446 for more details

Comment: services tend to be left on, any reason your switching it on and off?

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing it to elevate in the batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Automatically elevate...

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: Check if script was run with administrator privilages
    >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

:: If the error flag is set, we do not have admin.
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO GOTADMIN

:UACPROMPT
    ECHO. Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    ECHO. UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    "%TEMP%\getadmin.vbs"
    EXIT /B

:GOTADMIN
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    CD /D "%~dp0"
ENDLOCAL
GOTO SCRIPTSTART


:: THE ACTUAL SCRIPT STARTS HERE
:SCRIPTSTART
NET START [whatever service]
```