# how to check if the services stopped

Tags: service, batch-file

I have done a batch file that stop the services, delete files, install files, and start the services.
till now it didn't have any trouble. but today it failed to install the files.

After a little search I have seen that the services are on stopping and not on stopped.
I am using **net stop "Service-Name"** to stop the services.

How can I check when the services are stopped or wait for them to completely stop?

Comment: See answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file or [How to check the exit code of the last command in batch file][1].


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/194662/how-to-check-the-exit-code-of-the-last-command-in-batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmic service where name="Service-Name" get state` will show you whether a service is running or stopped.  You can loop back to that command and use a ping to pause.

```
:running
ping /n 2 0.0.0.0 >NUL
for /f "tokens=2 delims=^=" %%I in ('wmic service where name^="Service-Name" get state /format:list') do (
    if #%%I==#Running goto running
)
rem When the script reaches this line, the service status is not "Running."
```

Or if you prefer using `sc` to determine the state of a service:

```
:running
ping /n 2 0.0.0.0 >NUL
for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('sc query Service-Name ^| find /i "state"') do (
    if #%%I==#RUNNING goto running
)
rem When the script reaches this line, the service status is not "Running."
```

I'm not certain, but it's possible that a service could say "stopped" when it's actually "stopping", or "running" when it's actually "starting."  If that's the case, then you might be better off checking whether a process exists in the process list.  That can also be done using wmic: `wmic process where name="appname.exe" get name` or similar.

Comment: this code : sc query Service-Name ^| find /i "state" was extremely helpful. thank you very much.