# Making sure DHCP Service is ready in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services, dhcp, netsh

I want to make a batch script that changes the IP of an interface on Windows XP. It is possible through the `netsh` utility:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection 2" static 10.0.2.2 255.255.255.0 none
```

However, the `netsh` utility requires the `dhcp` service to be enabled, even though we are setting a static address.

The script itself is not run by the user, but automatically when the system starts up, and it's not guaranteed that the `dhcp` service will be ready yet.

When I try to call `sc start dhcp`, the system returns the output immediately, even though the service is NOT ready yet (calling the `netsh` command afterwards will result in a `Failed to configure the DHCP service. The interfrace may be disconnected`).

When I wait 30 seconds between starting the service and running the `netsh` command, everything works fine. However just waiting is not the right way to handle this situation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmic` and `sc` can show you the running state of a service.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207787/1683264).

Something else of note:

While testing, it occurs to me that `net start` will block until complete, whereas `sc start` is non-blocking.  Is it possible for you to use `net` instead of `sc`?

Comment: The status that is returned by `wmic` and `sc` is incorrect. It returns "RUNNING" the second after you start the service, but the service is still unavailable.

Comment: @iTayb - Crap.  I was afraid of that.  But I did stumble upon something else that might interest you.  I edited my answer.