# Remote services

Tags: batch-file, remote-server, server

I have a remote server running services that need to be restarted from time to time. Every time I have to login using remote desktop to restart the services. I need something like a batch file that I can click from my workstation to get the services on the remote server to restart. I will welcome any thoughts/ideas to implement a tool that I can use to start my remote services at a click. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Are these windows services?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/133883/2152082 I would suggest to start a batchfile as scheduled task (onstart). No need to mess around from a workstation.