# Batch file for service

Tags: batch-file

I just need to create a batch file which can check service every minute and once the service going to `Stopped` so the Window CMD will close.

More clear:

1. Start service (do not close the CMD window)
2. Check every 1 min the service status
3. Once the service becomes to "Stopped" status close the CMD window

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop and Start a service via batch or cmd file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file)

Comment: it's doesn't connected to my request ...

Comment: @niallhaslam
i just need to create very small script that able to : start specific service (  , once the service will be "Stopped" so CMD window will be close ,  perhaps its complected script because the batch file needs check every 1 min what is the status . stooped or running , once it stopped , close the CMD window with Exit command . that it!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you have tried so far and why that didn't work?

Comment: Again, this what i have created :
@echo off 
net start "XXXX"
:1 
timeout 10 
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('sc XXXX ^| findstr STATE') do ( 
echo %%a 
if %%a==RUNNING echo The Service is up 
if %%a==RUNNING goto :1 
) 
exit 

 as you see , the script started specific service and after X time the script should check what is the status of service , as long as the script is running don't close CMD window (Batch file ) once the script will change status to "Stopped" close the CMD window (Batch file )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SC (service control) command, it gives you a lot more options.

DESCRIPTION:
          SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
          NT Service Controller and services.
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sc.php

USAGE:
      sc  [command] [service name]  ...

```
  The option <server> has the form "\\ServerName"
  Further help on commands can be obtained by typing: "sc [command]"
  Commands:
    query-----------Queries the status for a service, or
                    enumerates the status for types of services.
    queryex---------Queries the extended status for a service, or
                    enumerates the status for types of services.
    start-----------Starts a service.
    pause-----------Sends a PAUSE control request to a service.
    interrogate-----Sends an INTERROGATE control request to a service.
    continue--------Sends a CONTINUE control request to a service.
    stop------------Sends a STOP request to a service.
    config----------Changes the configuration of a service (persistant).
    description-----Changes the description of a service.
    failure---------Changes the actions taken by a service upon failure.
    qc--------------Queries the configuration information for a service.
    qdescription----Queries the description for a service.
    qfailure--------Queries the actions taken by a service upon failure.
    delete----------Deletes a service (from the registry).
    create----------Creates a service. (adds it to the registry).
    control---------Sends a control to a service.
    sdshow----------Displays a service's security descriptor.
    sdset-----------Sets a service's security descriptor.
    GetDisplayName--Gets the DisplayName for a service.
    GetKeyName------Gets the ServiceKeyName for a service.
    EnumDepend------Enumerates Service Dependencies.

  The following commands don't require a service name:
  sc <server> <command> <option>
    boot------------(ok | bad) Indicates whether the last boot should
                    be saved as the last-known-good boot configuration
    Lock------------Locks the Service Database
    QueryLock-------Queries the LockStatus for the SCManager Database
```

EXAMPLE:
          sc start MyService

Comment: Specifically, `for /f "tokens=1,4" %%a in ('sc query SERVICENAME') do if %%a == STATE set STATE=%%b` will set `STATE` to `RUNNING` or `STOPPED` (and occasionally some others).  You can then build this into an appropriate loop.

Comment: Hi   i don't want stop service , the service know alone stop itself after some minute , i just need that CMD file stay open while service is "Running " once it become to "Stopped" Close CMD window

Comment: I have created this one : 
@echo off 
net start "XXXX"
:1 
timeout 10 
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('sc XXXX ^| findstr STATE') do ( 
echo %%a 
if %%a==RUNNING echo The Service is up 
if %%a==RUNNING goto :1 
) 
exit 

 really start the service but not working well

Comment: @Merop4 The command I gave doesn't stop or start the service, just acquires its status so you can build that into your script.  If you've got a script that uses either this or your variant using `findstr` then edit that script into your question (so we can see it clearly) and specify **in what way** it doesn't do what you want.