# How to Install and manage a windows service in a node js app.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, windows-services, electron

I have a windows service,  i need to install it and manage it using my electron app.  What is the best way to do this?
Thanks.

**update**

Currently for installing a service i need to use

```
Installutil (path of my service)
```

And for starting `net start myservice`

Need to do this while installing my electron  app.

Comment: You can try to use this - https://github.com/tbenbrahim/windows-service-manager

Answer (score 0):

Related to this post [Stop and Start a service via batch or cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file#133926)

You can do exec with child process as example

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec('YOUR TERMINAL CODE HERE', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
//..
});
```