# How to get the startup type of a service with C #

Tags: c#, windows-services

As my client is not accustomed to using the windows services screen, I'm wondering what I do to get the type of startup of a service.

Comment: please check this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as using the [StartType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.starttype(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [`ServiceController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties) class :

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Simple Service");
Console.WriteLine(sc.StartType.ToString());
```

where "Simple Service" is the name of the service you want to get the details of.

More examples of using this class can be found [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

Comment: This option does not appear for me

Comment: Which option, `StartType`? If so, please upgrade your app .net version to .net 4.6.1. It is only available since then as stated in the docs.

Comment: Ok, I was using 4.5, I updated and it worked ... Thank you.