# Terminate service using Robot Framework Process Library

Tags: windows-services, robotframework

I am trying to terminate a service using PID/Servicename which is already in running state in the Windows services list.

I have tried "Process" Library and it works if I start a process from Robot Framework and terminate it using handle from there itself. But, not for the existing process in the Windows services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
${rc_code}    ${output}    Run And Return Rc And Output    taskkill /PID ${PID} /F /T
Run Keyword If    '${rc_code}' != '0'    Log    There was error during termination of process    WARN
```

Comment: It worked well, I also achieved it by calling a batch file with net start and stop command. However, your answer made the job much simpler. Is there a windows command to start a service as well?

Comment: `sc` - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/133926/3446126](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133926/3446126) - a google away :)