# Close the program using Robot Framework (Process Library)

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

Help me in a question, please:

I'm automating tests using the Robot Framework.
The interface is Desktop. I'm using the Sikuli and Process Libraries.

I use Process Library to open the program (Start Process).
How can i close de program using this library?
There are "Terminate Process" and "Terminate all Processes" Keywords, but they don't work for that purpose.

I found the link below, but don't help me... =/:
[Terminate service using Robot Framework Process Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942273/terminate-service-using-robot-framework-process-library)

Very thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? Terminate Process should do exactly what you need.

Comment: But how do i use?? I'm not getting. When i use Terminate Process, the program doesn't close... =/

Comment: Pekka, Do you have any example?

Comment: This is the simplest I could make, tested in Windows. I don't know how to add line breaks:

```*** Settings ***
Library    Process

*** Test Cases ***
Notepad
    ${process}=     Start Process    notepad
    Terminate Process```