# docker build - "error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running."

Tags: docker, build, docker-desktop, docker-daemon, docker-cli

I'm working on Windows 10 with the CLIs Git Bash, WSL2 and PowerShell. So far, I have not figured out how to make the command `docker build -t aws/codebuild/standard:3.0 .` work.

I've already tried several things:

1. In Git Bash: [net stop docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621129/restart-docker-windows-10-command-line/55212066#55212066)
2. Opening PowerShell in Admin-mode, restarting Docker Daemon via [cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker" && ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825#issuecomment-434267285)
3. Starting `dockerd` with admin rights on WSL2 - shell
4. Start "Docker Desktop" on Windows 10 manually until it states "Docker Service not running" (click on "start", "net" window opens and closes immediately, and nothing further happens):
   [image: docker_service_not_running]

Some more specifics on CLI outputs related to **Option 1**:

```
user@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0 (master)
$ net stop docker
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.


user@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0 (master)
$ net stop com.docker.service
The Docker Desktop Service service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.


user@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0 (master)
$ net start docker
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.


user@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0 (master)
$ net start com.docker.service
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.


user@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0 (master)
$ sudo net start com.docker.service
System error 1058 has occurred.

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

Some more specifics on WSL2-shell outputs with `dockerd` (**Option 3**):

```
user@hd1pcms0347:/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0$ docker build -t aws/codebuild/standard:3.0 .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

user@hd1pcms0347:/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0$ sudo dockerd
[sudo] password for user: 
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.569848200+02:00] Starting up
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.596368100+02:00] libcontainerd: started new containerd process  pid=3612
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.596759700+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.597062800+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.597402000+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.597708900+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.642947300+02:00] starting containerd                           revision= version="1.4.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2"
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.670987400+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.content.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.673888800+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.750046200+02:00] skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"...  error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.750651600+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.751899400+02:00] skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (wslfs) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.752328200+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.752652800+02:00] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper  error="devmapper not configured"
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.752973800+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.754531700+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.759859700+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.760367200+02:00] skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"...  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a 
zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.760925000+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"...  type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.762074700+02:00] could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin  error="devmapper not configured"
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.762472300+02:00] metadata content store policy set             policy=shared
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.769383900+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"...  type=io.containerd.differ.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.769855000+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"...  type=io.containerd.gc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.770209900+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.770586300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.771021300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.771445400+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.772519100+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.773311600+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.773761100+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.774170300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.774548800+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"...  type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.776950300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"...  type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.780732500+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"...  type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.782998700+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.783405000+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"...  type=io.containerd.internal.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.783818900+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.784270200+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.784640600+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.784918600+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.785216200+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.785516200+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.785764200+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.786065700+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.786339300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"...  type=io.containerd.internal.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.790367300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.790831300+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.791225900+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.791812700+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.794298100+02:00] serving...                                    address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.796248300+02:00] serving...                                    address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.797459100+02:00] serving...                                    address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.797772600+02:00] containerd successfully booted in 0.160923s
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.826449900+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.828408900+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.829324300+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.829885000+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.835378400+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.835778100+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.836458600+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.836858700+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.914129500+02:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit 
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.914502600+02:00] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.914702600+02:00] Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.914969800+02:00] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.915207100+02:00] Unable to find pids cgroup in mounts
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:18.915689900+02:00] Loading containers: start.
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:18.959628600+02:00] Running iptables --wait -t nat -L -n failed with message: `iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`, error: exit status 3
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:19.159782300+02:00] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:19.161237700+02:00] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
INFO[2021-06-30T15:04:19.161256700+02:00] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
WARN[2021-06-30T15:04:20.171320700+02:00] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc 
= "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting...  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)

user@hd1pcms0347:/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0$ docker build -t aws/codebuild/standard:3.0 .
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=aws%2Fcodebuild%2Fstandard%3A3.0&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

user@hd1pcms0347:/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/3.0$ sudo docker build -t aws/codebuild/standard:3.0 .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

---

**EDIT on 01-07-2021:**

I've managed to make docker work again by simply reinstalling it. Yet, I'd be delighted to know if there is any specific reason for the above-mentioned behavior.