# java.lang.InterruptedException while running a batch file

Tags: java, multithreading, batch-file, interrupted-exception

I am trying to run a batch file which has set of services I want to restart. When I call this batch file from my Java application I get Interrupted Exception.

My batch file

```
call net stop app-service
call net start app-service
call net stop ui-service
call net start ui-service
call net stop custom-app
call net start custom-app
call net stop MSSQLSERVER /Y
call net start MSSQLSERVER
```

My java code to run the batch file

```
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "restart.bat");
    String time="cmd /c "+file.getAbsolutePath();
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);         
    int exitvalue = p.waitFor();
```

I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:451)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not need to use `CALL`.

Comment: I removed the CALL Still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with the batch file. Calling stop and start immediately is what's causing the issue. Make sure the SQL server and services are stopped, then start the server and those services.

Please check this answer:

[Stop and Start a service via batch or cmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file)

> Use the SC (service control) command, it gives you a lot more options
> than just start & stop.
>
> DESCRIPTION:
> SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
> NT Service Controller and services.   USAGE:
> sc  [command] [service name]  ...
>
> ```
>   The option <server> has the form "\\ServerName"
>   Further help on commands can be obtained by typing: "sc [command]"
> ```